# Rails 5.2 upgrade causes ErrorController to fail with generic error page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling, ruby-on-rails-5

We're upgrading to Rails 5.2 from Rails 4 and our custom error pages have started to fail. This only happens on our QA server so far. If I set my development environment to show error pages, they work fine.

The log shows:

```
Processing by ErrorsController#not_found as HTML
Parameters: {"path"=>"does_not_exist"}
Rendering errors/not_found.html.haml
Rendered errors/not_found.html.haml (3.4ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

And the page response is a plain, unstyled generic message:

```
500 Internal Server Error
If you are the administrator of this website, then please read this web application's log file and/or the web server's log file to find out what went wrong.
```

The relevant method in the ErrorsController is:

```
class ErrorsController < ApplicationController

  def not_found
    error_tracking("404")
    fix_request_format

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render template: 'errors/not_found', :layout => false, status: 404 }
      format.all { render nothing: true, status: 404 }
    end
  end
```

What could be causing a 500 error AFTER the template has rendered?

Comment: What is the actual error from the log file? A 500 code is too generic to help with this issue

Comment: That's it I'm afraid. Which is why I'm on here. :/

Comment: Are you able to access any of the log files?

Comment: @AFaderDarkly are you sure generally there will be a stack trace after that explaining the error.

Comment: Yes, sadly there is no stack trace in this case. Things I will try next include checking the system log (just in case), removing Airbrake (which writes the only thing in the log after the 500 error) and eventually using a different technique for custom errors (maybe a concern type object mixed in to the application controller.)

Which is a shame, as I like the cleanness of a controller class.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with a similar problem, I ended up looking at the system log on the server. On my distro:

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/messages
```

This yielded the missing Ruby error:

```
Error during failsafe response: The asset "application_split2" is not present in the asset pipeline.
```

Which gave me a starting point for fixing the issue.